# Flutter post request, Requested entity was not found internal server error 500

Tags: c#, flutter, request

When I send a post request to the API in Flutter, I get an error:

> Requested entity was not found internal server error 500,

but this error does not always happen, sometimes it returns successful, sometimes it gives this error. But whether it gives an error or not, the post request is made, but I encounter this error and the response status code returns 500, not 200. I have the same problem when I try postman what could be the problem

The code is like this:

```
class JobOfferService {
  static Future<Object> postJobOffer(
      double amount, String message, JobModel job, int supplierId) async {
    var url =
        Uri.parse('${ApiConstants.baseUrl}${ApiConstants.joboffersEndpoint}');

    var body = jsonEncode({
      "customer_id": job.customerId,
      "supplier_id": supplierId,
      "job_id": job.id,
      "joboffer_total": amount,
      "job_offer_message": message,
    });

    try {
      var response = await http
          .post(url, body: body, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // İstek başarılı
        return Success(response: response.body);
      } else {
        // İstek başarısız
        return Failure(errorResponse: response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Log or print the actual error for debugging
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Error: $error');
      }

      // Return a more informative error message
      return Failure(
          code: UNKNOW_ERROR, errorResponse: 'Internal Server Error');
    }
  }
}
```

I checked the API side and whether permission is required or not, but the problem is not fixed.